# How to estimate a vocabulary size?

Tags: probability, parameter-estimation

I have a list of the 1 million most common English words ordered by number of times they appear on all books in Google Books. I want for the user to select from a list of 100 words (small sample) every word he knows.

I want to calculate how many words the user probably knows from the list, extrapolating from his answers in the small sample.

Supposing the sample is every 10th word from the 10th to the 1000th, what mathematical formula would give me the best result?

Comment: I accept answers with different sampling techniques

Comment: I should mention that the sampling also depends on your target audience. The average vocabulary for a native English speaker is estimated to be on the order of $10000$. The fact that you are using the top $1000$ words from Google Books, which are likely the $1000$ most common words in the English language, means that the majority of English speakers will likely know all or almost all of the words in your list. This may be a viable way to estimate the vocabulary of someone who has English as an auxiliary language, but probably not so much for someone with English as a primary language.

Comment: maybe I should get every 100th or 200th word from the list

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the probability that a user knows some word $w_{1}$ is equal to the probability that the user knows some word $w_{2}$ (and that these events are independent) for any two words $w_{1}$ and $w_{2}$, if a user knows $a$ out of $100$ words, a reasonable answer would be that they know $\frac{a}{100}n$ words out of an list of length $n$.

$n=1000$ in your example.

Also, since you have no beliefs about word knowledge, I don't know why you are sampling every 10th to make your list of 100.

Comment: but as the list progresses the rarity of the word increases, doesn't this fact influence the formula?

Comment: I agree with @JaderDias, it is completely unreasonable to assume that people know the words with equal probability.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed the part about "ordered by the number of occurrences"

Comment: I think this answer should be kept, it's a good answer, but maybe there are even better ones

Comment: good guy jader dias.